# My computer shuts down after boot up?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

I installed a fresh Windows 8 (Pro) on my PC and when it gets to the log in screen, it just shuts down? 

How can i fix this?

Comment: How did you install it? Did it happen after installing drivers maybe? Possibly not overheating is it?

Comment: What have you done so far? Is there any message at all? Do you have another OS installed to go poke? If its a fresh install, can you try re installing? And though its probably not important, which edition?

Comment: It is Window 8 Pro, clean HDD. just that nothing else on it.

Comment: @WillyWonka - Does your system actually turn off or does it reboot, it sounds like you have failing hardware, verify this happens in `Safe Mode`.

Comment: My computer is fine. It was in fact this Hybrid shutdown issue. It works fine now! Yay! Why did you downvote me?????

Comment: Wasn't me mate. Glad I could help- I just googled it. Lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some poking around and it seems there could be an issue with Hybrid Shutdown. This is along shot but this is how you can disable it.

1. Type power in Metro UI
2. Click on "Change what the power button does"
3. Disable "Turn on fast startup"
4. Apply - shutdown PC and start again.

You might need to do that in safe mode if you can get in that way... Buuut they changed something with safe mode... Hmm? [Read this](http://www.techspot.com/news/48718-windows-8-removes-need-for-f8-key-advanced-boot-menu-redesigned.html)

EDIT

If you cant get into safe mode try and do a normal full shutdown from power button on login screen? or just pull the power plug(I know-but that wont do the hybrid shut down thing and possibly let you in once to change the setting!)

Comment: Yes I managed to disable it- My it friend helped me do it with help of your post. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this on a guess, remove your battery and start your machine with the charger. While it is starting unplug your charger, replace the battery and let it start up the second time. It should take a little longer than before and should stay on.